# Inverse of an interval is not an open interval

Tags: real-analysis

Are there $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, with $\mathcal{D}(f)=\mathbb{R}$, for which there exists an open interval
$(a,b) \subset \mathcal{R}(f)$ such that $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is not an open interval ?

Is there a continuous function that has this property?

Comment: First 2 commenters: Yes the inverse image must be open if $f$ is continuous, but it doesn't have to be an interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ where $f(x)=x^2$.

Then $f^{-1}((1,4)) =(-2,-1)\cup (1,2)$. The inverse image of an open interval here is not an open interval.

Of course, the inverse image of any open set by any continuous function is open (that's the definition of a continuous function), but not necessarily an open interval.

**Addendum:** In fact, $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is an interval if and only if $0\in (a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Take  $f$ a periodic function defined on $R$ such that for $x$ integer, $f(x)=2$ and for $x$ between $0$ and $1$, $f(x)=x$. Then $f^{-1}((0,1))$ is not a single open interval but infinitly many.